# How to sum values from same names?

Tags: r

R program

I need to sum values from same names which are repeated in a list.

I have a list like,

```
  Person  Money
1  1        3
2  2        1
3  1        2
4  3        1
5  2        1
```

I need,

```
  Person  Money
1  1    (3+2=)5
2  2        2
3  3        1
```

Comment: `aggregate(Money ~ Person, data=df, sum)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `ddply` from `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
z=data.frame(ddply(YourDataFrame,.(Person),summarise))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the base function tapply.

```
df = data.frame(Person=c("Joe","Joe","Fred","Jane","Fred","Jane"), Money=c(2,5,2,1,7,2))
tapply(df$Money, df$Person, FUN=sum)
```